# Disable cursor and copy/paste in UITextView (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a `UITextField` for which I am using `UIPickerView` as its `inputView`. The user can select a value from the picker, and the selected value gets populated into my `TextInput`. 

This arrangement works fine, but with the following issues:

1) I want to disable the cursor that still shows in the `UITextField`. 

I tried disabling the `UITextField`, but then it does not respond to touches and then the `UIPickerView` does not show - which makes it useless.
2) Since the picker is shown and the keyboard is not wen the user taps on the text-field, the user cannot type anything, but still can paste text copied from else where by long pressing. How can I disable this?

I am not able to find the relevant information online. Should I be using a `Label` or a `Button` for this instead of the `UITextInput`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easy way is to make it with a button instead `UITextField`

Sorry - this is not for `Swift` it's for `Obj-C` but this is the idea:

To do what you want with `UITextField` you have to subclass the `UITextField` and try to use this code to disable/hide caret and input (copy/paste)

```
- (CGRect) caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition*) position
{
    return CGRectZero;
}

- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range
{
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(selectAll:) || action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        returnNO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

example from here: http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/disabling-the-caret-and-text-entry-in-uitextfields/

Anyway... this is a "functional" example: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQDropDownTextField

Comment: This is a great solution for anyone trying to keep the dataDetectorTypes feature in tact without allowing the user to select (i.e. copy, select all, look up) the rest of the text around the actionable data. 

Thanks @TonyMkenu

Answer (score 8):

Like TonyMkenu said, you need to subclass UITextField and then implement the methods he has above. Here's the Swift for those of you who don't know Objective C:

```
override func caretRectForPosition(position: UITextPosition!) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect.zeroRect
}

override func selectionRectsForRange(range: UITextRange) -> [AnyObject] {
    return []
}

override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    // Disable copy, select all, paste
    if action == Selector("copy:") || action == Selector("selectAll:") || action == Selector("paste:") {
        return false
    }
    // Default
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT 4**

Create TextField.swift file & change import Foundation to import UIKit & add following code in TextFeild.swift file

```
import UIKit

class TextFeild: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // write code here what ever you want to change property for textfeild. 
    }

    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    override func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [Any] {
        return []
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        // Default
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Go to main.storyboard, select that textfield & change its custom class to TextField

[image: Xcode Image]

Comment: Great solution. Just noted that selectionRects should return  [UITextSelectionRect]:               override func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [UITextSelectionRect] {  
        return []  
    }

Answer (score 2):

Totally silly hack, but if you set the text field's tint color in the `UIView` section of the Interface Builder property inspector to match the background color, the cursor will appear invisible:

[image]

Comment: Though i have upvoted for your answer as it will hide the cursor but copy paste option would still be there.

Comment: Yeah, silly hack. Also far more complicated now that we have dark mode and other dynamic themes.

Comment: why not: textField.tintColor = .clear

Answer (score 1):

The `UITextField` delegate can implement the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method. If that method always returns `NO`, then the cursor will never appear and the long press won't be allowed.

When the method is called, you can display the `UIPickerView`. However, the `UIPickerView` cannot be an `inputView`. It would need to be the child of a standard `UIView` that you animate in from the bottom. Or you could just use the `hidden` property of the `UIView` to hide/show the view as needed.

Comment: I see, so my approach of using `UIPickerView` as the `inputView` for the `UITextView` is wrong. Can you point me to an example, or something similar to do it the right way?

Comment: Yeah, that becomes problematic, because I still use objective-C, and I avoid auto-layout whenever possible, so I can help with concepts, but not so much with the code.